# $A_i$ are closed. Any compact set intersects with finitely many $A_i$. Is $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$ closed?

Tags: general-topology

I do not know if this proposition is true.

My guess: yes?

my attempts:

Take a convergent net $a_\lambda\to a_0$ from $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$.

1. Suppose there is some $i$ such that for every $\lambda$ there is $\eta\geq\lambda$ such that $a_\eta\in A_i$. Then $a_\eta$ such that $a_\eta\in A_i$ forms a subnet of $a$ and therefore converges to $a_0$. This shows $a_0\in A_i$.
2. Suppose there is not, so that there are increasing $\lambda_i$ such that element of $A_i$ does not appear after $\lambda_i$. Samely, $a_{\lambda_i}\to a_0$, and therefore $\{a_0,a_{\lambda_1},...\}$ is compact. By the assumption it only intersects with finitely many $A_i$, but this is a contradiction.

I did it! Is this proof correct then?

By the way, is there some weaker condition which makes $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i$ a closed set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false, I’m afraid.

Let $p$ be a free (i.e., non-principal) ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, and let $X=\Bbb N\cup\{p\}$. Let

$$\tau=\wp(\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{p\}\cup A:A\in p\big\}\,;$$

$\tau$ is a topology on $X$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A_n=\{n\}$. The sets $A_n$ are closed, and the only compact sets in $X$ are the finite sets, so every compact subset of $X$ intersects only finitely many of the sets $A_n$. However, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\Bbb N$, which is not closed: $p$ is a limit point of $\Bbb N$.

The problem with your argument is that the sequence $\langle a_{\lambda_i}:i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ need not converge to $a_0$.

**Added:** To see that every compact subset of $X$ is finite, let $A\subseteq X$ be infinite. Clearly $A$ is not compact if $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, so suppose that $p\in A$. If $A\notin p$, then $\Bbb N\setminus A\in p$, so $X\setminus A$ is an open nbhd of $p$, and

$$\{X\setminus A\}\cup\big\{\{n\}:n\in A\big\}$$

is an open cover of $A$ with no finite subcover. If $A\in p$, let $\{B,C\}$ be a partition of $A$ into two infinite sets. Since $p$ is an ultrafilter, exactly one of $B$ and $C$ belongs to $p$; without loss of generality suppose that $B\in p$. Then

$$\big\{\{p\}\cup B\big\}\cup\big\{\{n\}:n\in A\setminus B\big\}$$

is an open cover of $A$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Does free mean it contains all cofinite sets?

Comment: @Yuz: It implies that, yes. But it also contains co-infinite sets. In fact, if $A\in p$, and $A=B\cup C$, where $B$ and $C$ are disjoint infinite subsets of $A$, then exactly one of $B$ and $C$ belongs to $p$.

Comment: $X=\Bbb N\cup\{p\}$
You mean, $X$ is $\mathbb N$ plus a single point?
Or do you mean $X=\mathbb N\cup p$ ?

Comment: @Yuz: I mean what I wrote: $X$ is $\Bbb N$ plus a single point.

Comment: I see where my proof goes wrong. $\lim a_i=a_0$ doesn't mean $\{a_0,a_1,...\}$ is compact. Thank you!

Comment: @Yuz: You’re welcome!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong it was the 'incrasing $\lambda_i$' part that was not correct. $a_{\lambda_i}\not\to a_0$

Answer (score 1):

If $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of closed sets and is also locally finite ( every point $x\in X$ is contained in some $U_x$ open such that $U_x$ intersects finitely many of the $A_i$'s ) then $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ is closed.

For proof: a set is closed if and only it is locally closed ( since it is true for "open").

Now, if your space is also locally compact then OK.